# Spurious leading horizontal space with \multicolumn in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

When I use a `\multicolumn` within a `tabular` (or `tabularx`) there seems to be additional horizontal spacing added at the beginning of the column even though the `l`eft alignment was specified for `\multicolumn`.  The last line in this table shows this issue:

[image]

Why is the spacing there, and how do I eliminate it?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=7.0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X l l@{}}
Sub Item 1 & 3,000 \\
Sub Item 2 & 4,000 \\
Total      &       & 7,000 \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{$\leftarrow$ Why is there space to the left of this?} \\
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip
\par\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l l@{}}
Sub Item 1 & 3,000 \\
Sub Item 2 & 4,000 \\
Total      &       & 7,000 \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{$\leftarrow$ Why is there space to the left of this?} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to use `\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{` as `\multicolumn` overrides previous settings.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Dammm!! So its a general `tabular` issue and not something specific to `tabularx`. Can't believe I have not encountered that problem with `tabular` before.  Have edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is determined by the `\arraycolsep` parameter. If you question means "how to avoid this skip", the solution is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=7.0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X l l@{}}
Sub Item 1 & 3,000 \\
Sub Item 2 & 4,000 \\
Total      &       & 7,000 \\
%\multicolumn{3}{l}{$\leftarrow$ Why is there space to the left of this?} \\
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{$\leftarrow$ Why is there space to the left of this?} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```